# AWS Amplify CLI failing to deploy API with Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify-cli

I am using the amplify CLI tool to create the serverless backend of my React demo app.  I have created a storage (using amplify add storage) which is a DynamoDB table. Then I created a Python lambda function, where I told amplify-cli that it needs to access another resource (pointing it to the DynamoDB table). At this point, I thought that the amplify-cli tool will add permissions to the lambda to access the DyanmoDB table. Then I create an API (REST) using the amplify-cli which uses the lambda I have created.

Now in my React app, I want to make a request to that API end-point, which is going to trigger the lambda, the lambda will retrieve data from DynamoDB, and return a response.

I deployed the backend using “amplify push”

However, I have two problems:

1. When I go to the AWS dashboard to test the deployed function, when I run a test from the AWS Console, I see an error saying that the lambda is now allowed to access the DynamoDB table. I then went to IAM and found the policy and I added "DynamoDB Read Access". This solved the access problem; however, I still want to know how I could do this at the amplify-cli level instead of manually doing it through AWS Console. I understand my fix is not portable, and ideally the amplify-cli should have handled this for me, is it possible?
2. After the (1) fix, my React app still fails to access the API with the following error: "Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 400". I understand that this is a CORS error, but my lambda, in its response it returns:

```
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
            },
            'data': my_data
        }
```

Also, when creating the end-point, to the question “restriction” I said “no”.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding issue (1), it might be silly but figured it out, during the wizard of creating the lambda function with the Amplify-CLI, when you say "Advanced Configuration" and then asks you to link to "Storage" so it will grant permissions to lambda to work with DynamoDB, you have to use **the space bar** to select the options!

Comment: Does your API gateway have proxy integration enabled?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes

Comment: what values are returned for `Access-Control-Allow-*` in the response within your dev tools in the browser?

Comment: I think the problem originates also from the AWS Cognito. It gives "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()". The thing is, to be able to make a call to the API, it required the creation of auth, so I did `amplify add auth` and used the default settings.

Comment: Does your CORS endpoint mistakenly have auth enabled in the API gateway? There's quite a few questions and problems here

Comment: Thanks for your time. I created the api using the `amplify add api`, so it only asked me to provide a name of the api and a path and a lambda to trigger. Nothing else did I configured. When I deployed, the browser, complain with `Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.  The configuration object is missing required auth properties.` I don't completely understand why auth is needed. I have now removed the auth (ran `amplify remove auth`) because I still think is not needed, the question is why is the API asking for it.